# Redgate SQL Monitor base monitor permissions

Tags: sql-server, windows, monitoring, redgate

I'm setting up Redgate's SQL Monitor. The *Base Monitor* is the bit that actually collects data from monitored SQL Server instances and their hosts. [This page](http://www.red-gate.com/supportcenter/content/SQL_Monitor/help/3.2/SM_Account_Permissions) describes the permissions required by accounts running the various components, and asserts that the account "should be an administrator on the machine".

We don't want this account to be an admin, for a number of reasons. **Is there a list of the actual, fine-grained permissions required to run this?**

First stab includes:

- Maybe membership of Performance Monitor Users
- Maybe membership of Performance Log Users
- Maybe membership of Event Log Readers
- WMI - Remote Enable on root\CIMV2 ([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188690%28v=sql.110%29.aspx))
- Needs to be able to read at least parts of the registry (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation`)

At the moment I'm just chasing down each one and find a permissions that allows it, but it's pretty tedious.

Answer (score 1):

I know your original post was about 2 years ago, but wanted to say that Red Gate has updated permissions to be a bit more granular for the Base Monitor Service.
Please see the following for more details:
[SQL Monitor Permissions](http://documentation.red-gate.com/display/SM4/Requirements)

Also, I find the that the following link is pretty helpful in terms of troubleshooting permissions or connections issues for SQL Monitor:

[Test Data Collection](http://documentation.red-gate.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=20743047)

It may be a couple of years late, but hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Red Gate doesn't have a list of specific permissions that will work. I'm pretty sure that the help page says the account has to be an administrator because you need that to access the performance counters remotely.

Comment: You don't have to be an admin to access performance counters if you have the appropriate, more fine-grained, permissions. That's what groups like Performance Monitor Users are for.